# Async pipe cannot be found when passing to child component

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-pipe

I am trying to pass a variable to a child component in congruence with the async pipe. I can display that data with the pipe and it works fine. However, when I try to pass the data, there is an error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The pipe 'async' could not be found!
```

Error: The pipe 'async' could not be found!

Component view

```
<!-- CONTENT -->
<div class="content">

    {{(userInfo | async)?.data()}}   // This works fine if the below is not included

    <mat-tab-group dynamicHeight="true"
                   style="width:60%; margin:0px 20%;">


        // This produces an error
        <mat-tab label="Bio">
            <profile-about [userData]='userData' [userInfo]='userInfo | async'></profile-about>
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab label="Companies">
            <profile-companies [userData]='userData' [userInfo]='userInfo | async'></profile-companies>
        </mat-tab>

    </mat-tab-group>

</div>
<!-- / CONTENT -->
```

I have seen this done in [articles](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/) and it seems simple. There is some discussion that another module - the commonModule needs to be included but that makes little sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by `userInfo | pipe`, I assume it's `userInfo | async`. Nevertheless to use a value obtained using `async` pipe multiple times, you could wrap it in a container using `*ngIf` directive. Try the following

```html
<div class="content">
  <ng-container *ngIf="userInfo | async as info">
    {{ info?.data() }}

    <mat-tab-group dynamicHeight="true" style="width:60%; margin:0px 20%;">
      <mat-tab label="Bio">
        <profile-about [userData]="userData" [userInfo]="info"></profile-about>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Companies">
        <profile-companies [userData]="userData" [userInfo]="info"></profile-companies>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Also note if the `async` pipe is used with observables from HttpClient, then each pipe could trigger an individual HTTP request.

Comment: I edited the above. It was supposed to be "async". I implemented the solution of wrapping in a container and still got the error "The pipe 'async' could not be found!"

Comment: Do you have multiple modules in your app?

Comment: Yes. Several modules. Why?

Comment: The component shown above is a child module. The async pipe is working in the one instance and not in the ngIf directive.

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite follow you. In my answer, there is only one occurrence of the `async` pipe, with the `*ngIf` directive.

Comment: OK. So I added the common module and that solved the problem. The problem itself eludes me. The component that housed the html above was not the app.module and yet the async pipe worked when enclosed by brackets {{}} and could not be found when used in the ngIf directive or when passed to a child component. This makes no sense to me.